# IllegalArgumentException null ClassLoader Issue

Tags: java, illegalargumentexception

I am getting an `IllegalArgumentException` when I attempt to load a class that describes a `JMenuItem`'s properties from a list. To help out, I am including the pertinent parts of my API and the code that causes this exception.

The API is as follows:

```java
public interface MenuCommand extends Comparable<MenuCommand> {
    public String getName();
    public String getOwner();
    public int getPosition();
    public String getActionName();
    public default boolean separatorBefore() { return false; }
    public default boolean separatorAfter() { return false; }
}
```

This interface defines the `javax.swing.JMenuItem` that will be created in my application's `initialize` method. However, since I am making the application completely pluggable, I actually instantiate the various `MenuCommand` classes in the individual module's using the following interface:

```java
public interface Plugin {
    public String getVersion();
    public OptionsPanelProvider getOptionsPanel(); // A custom JPanel implementation.
    public List<MenuCommand> getMenuItems(); // Retrieves all of the items I am having the issue with.
    public List<MenuProvider> getMenus(); // Works as expected in the application.
    public List<ToolbarCommand> getToolbarButtons(); // May experience this same issue again loading these...
    public String getPluginName();
    public String getVendorName();
    public String getCopyright();
    public default List<String> getContributors() { return Collections.emptyList(); }
}
```

My application's `initialize()` method calls a private method called `loadModules`, which loads all of the latter interface implementations into an `ArrayList<Plugin>` variable. Once the plugin modules are loaded, I call a method named `buildMainMenu`, which pulls all of the `MenuProvider`s out of each plugin and loads them into the main window's menubar, and this method works perfectly.

Once the main menubar has all of the top-level and sub-menus loaded into it from the various installed plugins, `initialize` then calls `addMenuItems` to load the former (`MenuCommand`) interface implementations into the appropriate menus, and that is where this exception is thrown. Here is the code that is not working:

```java
private void addMenuItems() {
    List<MenuCommand> allCommands = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Plugin p : modules) {
        allCommands.addAll(p.getMenuItems());
    }

    Collections.sort(allCommands); // Hence the extension of Comparable on the interface.

    javax.swing.JMenuBar bar = mainWindow.getMenuBar();
    for (int x = 0; x < bar.getMenuCount(); x++) {
        javax.swing.JMenu m = bar.getMenu(x);

        for (MenuCommand c : allCommands) {
            if (m.getName().equals(c.getOwner())) {
                m.add(createJMenuItem(c));
            }
        }
    }
}

private javax.swing.JMenuItem createJMenuItem(MenuCommand c) {
    ResourceMap resMap = getContext().getResourceMap(c.getClass());

    //vvv This is the line throwing the exception vvv\\
    ActionMap actMap = getContext().getActionMap(c.getClass());

    javax.swing.JMenuItem item = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    item.setName(c.getName());
    item.setAction(actMap.getAction(c.getActionName()));
    getContext().getSessionStorage().injectComponent(item);

    return item;
}
```

If the individual `MenuCommand` implementations that are stored in the `Plugin`'s `getMenuItems` list have already been initialized (loaded), they should have a `ClassLoader` associated with them. When I break execution on the problem line, the `c` class has a `ClassLoader`, but I do see a couple of `null` property values:

```
c.getClass().getClassLoader().URLClassPath = #1975
c.getClass().getClassLoader().URLClassPath.path = ArrayList.size = 0
c.getClass().getClassLoader().URLClassPath.unopenedUrls = ArrayDeque.size = 0
c.getClass().getClassLoader().URLClassPath.loaders = ArrayList.size = 0
c.getClass().getClassLoader().URLClassPath.Imap = HashMap.size = 0
c.getClass().getClassLoader().URLClassPath.jarHandler = null
c.getClass().getClassLoader().URLClassPath.closed = false
c.getClass().getClassLoader().URLClassPath.acc = null
```

Furthermore, from the `static` section of the `ClassLoader`, the `usr_paths` array has a length of 5, containing various JDK-related paths. The `sys_paths` array has a length of 1, pointing to the `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.12/lib` folder, as it should. The `packageToModule` array has a size of 1079. The `ClassLoader$AppClassLoader` properties are identical to those listed above.

#### Attempts to solve

In an attempt to solve this issue, I have tried not using the `List<Plugin> modules.getMenuItems()` method, but to use the `ServiceLoader<MenuCommand>.load` method to see if that would do it, but it did not.

I have read through numerous `ServiceLoader`, `ClassLoader`, and other documentation, including the book about the Java Virtual Machine that I have, but have not been able to discover what I am missing.

I have looked at other questions about similar issues, but they have not helped either. I am hoping that posting this question will find me some help. Thank you all for your assistance.

-SC

***UPDATE*** `getResourceMap()` and `getActionMap()` are part of a slightly updated version of the JSR-296 `org.jdesktop` AppFramework. Here is the full stacktrace:

```
Dec 01, 2021 8:33:28 AM org.jdesktop.application.Application$1 run
SEVERE: Application class com.gs.nta.NTApp failed to launch
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null ClassLoader
    at appframework@1.0.3/org.jdesktop.application.ResourceMap.<init>(ResourceMap.java:152)
    at appframework@1.0.3/org.jdesktop.application.ResourceManager.createResourceMap(ResourceManager.java:436)
    at appframework@1.0.3/org.jdesktop.application.ResourceManager.createResourceMapChain(ResourceManager.java:139)
    at appframework@1.0.3/org.jdesktop.application.ResourceManager.getClassResourceMap(ResourceManager.java:173)
    at appframework@1.0.3/org.jdesktop.application.ResourceManager.getResourceMap(ResourceManager.java:254)
    at appframework@1.0.3/org.jdesktop.application.ApplicationContext.getResourceMap(ApplicationContext.java:203)
    at appframework@1.0.3/org.jdesktop.application.ActionManager.getActionMap(ActionManager.java:168)
    at appframework@1.0.3/org.jdesktop.application.ApplicationContext.getActionMap(ApplicationContext.java:303)
    at NTA.Foundation/com.gs.nta.NTApp.createJMenuItem(NTApp.java:709)
    at NTA.Foundation/com.gs.nta.NTApp.addMenuItems(NTApp.java:636)
    at NTA.Foundation/com.gs.nta.NTApp.initialize(NTApp.java:171)
    at appframework@1.0.3/org.jdesktop.application.Application$1.run(Application.java:170)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Application class com.gs.nta.NTApp failed to launch
    at appframework@1.0.3/org.jdesktop.application.Application$1.run(Application.java:177)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null ClassLoader
    at appframework@1.0.3/org.jdesktop.application.ResourceMap.<init>(ResourceMap.java:152)
    at appframework@1.0.3/org.jdesktop.application.ResourceManager.createResourceMap(ResourceManager.java:436)
    at appframework@1.0.3/org.jdesktop.application.ResourceManager.createResourceMapChain(ResourceManager.java:139)
    at appframework@1.0.3/org.jdesktop.application.ResourceManager.getClassResourceMap(ResourceManager.java:173)
    at appframework@1.0.3/org.jdesktop.application.ResourceManager.getResourceMap(ResourceManager.java:254)
    at appframework@1.0.3/org.jdesktop.application.ApplicationContext.getResourceMap(ApplicationContext.java:203)
    at appframework@1.0.3/org.jdesktop.application.ActionManager.getActionMap(ActionManager.java:168)
    at appframework@1.0.3/org.jdesktop.application.ApplicationContext.getActionMap(ApplicationContext.java:303)
    at NTA.Foundation/com.gs.nta.NTApp.createJMenuItem(NTApp.java:709)
    at NTA.Foundation/com.gs.nta.NTApp.addMenuItems(NTApp.java:636)
    at NTA.Foundation/com.gs.nta.NTApp.initialize(NTApp.java:171)
    at appframework@1.0.3/org.jdesktop.application.Application$1.run(Application.java:170)
    ... 13 more
```

***UPDATE 2*** And, just for additional application flow information, here is the output of my logger:

```
[ENTER] (2021-12-01T14:33:27.942336Z): [SEQ 1]: com.gs.nta.NTApp.initialize - Initializing application and all objects. | (Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 [ID=16; PRIORITY=6; STATE=RUNNABLE]: Parameter(s): [--ide]
[ENTER] (2021-12-01T14:33:27.964177Z): [SEQ 3]: com.gs.nta.NTApp.parseArguments - Parsing command-line arguments. | (Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 [ID=16; PRIORITY=6; STATE=RUNNABLE]: Parameter(s): [--ide]
TRACE (2021-12-01T14:33:27.966121Z): [SEQ 6]: com.gs.nta.NTApp.parseArguments - development.mode=true; logger.level=TRACE | (Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 [ID=16; PRIORITY=6; STATE=RUNNABLE]: Parameter(s): [--ide]
CONFIG (2021-12-01T14:33:27.969736Z): [SEQ 7]: com.gs.nta.NTApp.parseArguments - Checking to see if the formatted logs argument is present. | (Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 [ID=16; PRIORITY=6; STATE=RUNNABLE]: Parameter(s): [--ide]
TRACE (2021-12-01T14:33:27.969981Z): [SEQ 8]: com.gs.nta.NTApp.parseArguments - logging.format=false | (Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 [ID=16; PRIORITY=6; STATE=RUNNABLE]: Parameter(s): [--ide]
[EXIT] (2021-12-01T14:33:27.970190Z): [SEQ 9]: com.gs.nta.NTApp.parseArguments - Done parsing command-line arguments. | (Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 [ID=16; PRIORITY=6; STATE=RUNNABLE]
[ENTER] (2021-12-01T14:33:27.970608Z): [SEQ 10]: com.gs.nta.NTApp.loadModules - Loading modules: | (Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 [ID=16; PRIORITY=6; STATE=RUNNABLE]
CONFIG (2021-12-01T14:33:27.980256Z): [SEQ 11]: com.gs.nta.NTApp.loadModules - Plugin Loaded: NTA Properties Manager (GS United Labs) v. NTA_Properties_Manager-1.0-DEV-SNAPSHOT | (Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 [ID=16; PRIORITY=6; STATE=RUNNABLE]
CONFIG (2021-12-01T14:33:27.993990Z): [SEQ 12]: com.gs.nta.NTApp.loadModules - Plugin Loaded: Logging System (GS United Labs) v. Logging_System-5.0-SNAPSHOT | (Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 [ID=16; PRIORITY=6; STATE=RUNNABLE]
CONFIG (2021-12-01T14:33:27.994537Z): [SEQ 13]: com.gs.nta.NTApp.loadModules - Plugin Loaded: Northwind Traders Foundation (GS United Labs) v. Northwind_Traders_Foundation-1.0-DEV-SNAPSHOT | (Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 [ID=16; PRIORITY=6; STATE=RUNNABLE]
[EXIT] (2021-12-01T14:33:27.994737Z): [SEQ 14]: com.gs.nta.NTApp.loadModules - Done loading modules. | (Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 [ID=16; PRIORITY=6; STATE=RUNNABLE]
[ENTER] (2021-12-01T14:33:28.045044Z): [SEQ 15]: com.gs.nta.NTApp.buildMainMenu - Building menu system... | (Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 [ID=16; PRIORITY=6; STATE=RUNNABLE]
DEBUG (2021-12-01T14:33:28.045355Z): [SEQ 16]: com.gs.nta.NTApp.buildMainMenu - Getting all menus from all installed modules. | (Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 [ID=16; PRIORITY=6; STATE=RUNNABLE]
TRACE (2021-12-01T14:33:28.047357Z): [SEQ 17]: com.gs.nta.NTApp.buildMainMenu - Retrieved 6 menus from installed modules. | (Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 [ID=16; PRIORITY=6; STATE=RUNNABLE]
DEBUG (2021-12-01T14:33:28.047727Z): [SEQ 18]: com.gs.nta.NTApp.buildMainMenu - Getting only top-level menus from the list of all menus. | (Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 [ID=16; PRIORITY=6; STATE=RUNNABLE]
TRACE (2021-12-01T14:33:28.047883Z): [SEQ 19]: com.gs.nta.NTApp.buildMainMenu - Of all 6 menus, 5 were top-level menus. | (Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 [ID=16; PRIORITY=6; STATE=RUNNABLE]
TRACE (2021-12-01T14:33:28.048127Z): [SEQ 20]: com.gs.nta.NTApp.buildMainMenu - Of all 6 menus, 5 were menu items. | (Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 [ID=16; PRIORITY=6; STATE=RUNNABLE]
[ENTER] (2021-12-01T14:33:28.065047Z): [SEQ 21]: com.gs.nta.NTApp.createJMenu - Creating a java.awt.Menu from the MenuProvider: com.gs.nta.menus.FileMenuProvider@7e9d8d7b | (Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 [ID=16; PRIORITY=6; STATE=RUNNABLE]: Parameter(s): [com.gs.nta.menus.FileMenuProvider@7e9d8d7b]

>>> Exception stacktrace located here <<<

[EXIT] (2021-12-01T14:33:28.075770Z): [SEQ 22]: com.gs.nta.NTApp.createJMenu - Menu javax.swing.JMenu[fileMenu,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalBorders$MenuItemBorder@74ee4a2b,flags=256,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=2,left=2,bottom=2,right=2],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=false,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=false,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=File] created and returned. | (Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 [ID=16; PRIORITY=6; STATE=RUNNABLE]: Parameter(s): [com.gs.nta.menus.FileMenuProvider@7e9d8d7b]
[ENTER] (2021-12-01T14:33:28.226546Z): [SEQ 23]: com.gs.nta.NTApp.createJMenu - Creating a java.awt.Menu from the MenuProvider: com.gs.nta.menus.EditMenuProvider@6b3f648a | (Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 [ID=16; PRIORITY=6; STATE=RUNNABLE]: Parameter(s): [com.gs.nta.menus.EditMenuProvider@6b3f648a]
[EXIT] (2021-12-01T14:33:28.228859Z): [SEQ 24]: com.gs.nta.NTApp.createJMenu - Menu javax.swing.JMenu[editMenu,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalBorders$MenuItemBorder@74ee4a2b,flags=256,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=2,left=2,bottom=2,right=2],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=false,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=false,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=Edit] created and returned. | (Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 [ID=16; PRIORITY=6; STATE=RUNNABLE]: Parameter(s): [com.gs.nta.menus.EditMenuProvider@6b3f648a]
[ENTER] (2021-12-01T14:33:28.229384Z): [SEQ 25]: com.gs.nta.NTApp.createJMenu - Creating a java.awt.Menu from the MenuProvider: com.gs.nta.menus.ViewMenuProvider@26a1a787 | (Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 [ID=16; PRIORITY=6; STATE=RUNNABLE]: Parameter(s): [com.gs.nta.menus.ViewMenuProvider@26a1a787]
[EXIT] (2021-12-01T14:33:28.231477Z): [SEQ 26]: com.gs.nta.NTApp.createJMenu - Menu javax.swing.JMenu[viewMenu,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalBorders$MenuItemBorder@74ee4a2b,flags=256,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=2,left=2,bottom=2,right=2],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=false,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=false,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=View] created and returned. | (Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 [ID=16; PRIORITY=6; STATE=RUNNABLE]: Parameter(s): [com.gs.nta.menus.ViewMenuProvider@26a1a787]
[ENTER] (2021-12-01T14:33:28.232001Z): [SEQ 27]: com.gs.nta.NTApp.createJMenu - Creating a java.awt.Menu from the MenuProvider: com.gs.nta.menus.ToolsMenuProvider@2b41cd51 | (Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 [ID=16; PRIORITY=6; STATE=RUNNABLE]: Parameter(s): [com.gs.nta.menus.ToolsMenuProvider@2b41cd51]
[EXIT] (2021-12-01T14:33:28.234856Z): [SEQ 28]: com.gs.nta.NTApp.createJMenu - Menu javax.swing.JMenu[toolsMenu,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalBorders$MenuItemBorder@74ee4a2b,flags=256,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=2,left=2,bottom=2,right=2],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=false,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=false,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=Tools] created and returned. | (Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 [ID=16; PRIORITY=6; STATE=RUNNABLE]: Parameter(s): [com.gs.nta.menus.ToolsMenuProvider@2b41cd51]
[ENTER] (2021-12-01T14:33:28.235381Z): [SEQ 29]: com.gs.nta.NTApp.createJMenu - Creating a java.awt.Menu from the MenuProvider: com.gs.nta.menus.HelpMenuProvider@2ee9de63 | (Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 [ID=16; PRIORITY=6; STATE=RUNNABLE]: Parameter(s): [com.gs.nta.menus.HelpMenuProvider@2ee9de63]
[EXIT] (2021-12-01T14:33:28.237675Z): [SEQ 30]: com.gs.nta.NTApp.createJMenu - Menu javax.swing.JMenu[helpMenu,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalBorders$MenuItemBorder@74ee4a2b,flags=256,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=2,left=2,bottom=2,right=2],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=false,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=false,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=Help] created and returned. | (Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 [ID=16; PRIORITY=6; STATE=RUNNABLE]: Parameter(s): [com.gs.nta.menus.HelpMenuProvider@2ee9de63]
TRACE (2021-12-01T14:33:28.238275Z): [SEQ 31]: com.gs.nta.NTApp.createJMenu - Built the java.awt.MenuBar (javax.swing.JMenuBar[menuBar,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.plaf.basic.DefaultMenuLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalBorders$MenuBarBorder@3ee2e400,flags=392,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,margin=,paintBorder=true]) and setting it as the menuBar on the mainFrame. | (Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 [ID=16; PRIORITY=6; STATE=RUNNABLE]: Parameter(s): [com.gs.nta.menus.HelpMenuProvider@2ee9de63]
TRACE (2021-12-01T14:33:28.239715Z): [SEQ 32]: com.gs.nta.NTApp.createJMenu - mainWindow.getJMenuBar() == javax.swing.JMenuBar[menuBar,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.plaf.basic.DefaultMenuLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalBorders$MenuBarBorder@3ee2e400,flags=392,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,margin=,paintBorder=true] | (Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 [ID=16; PRIORITY=6; STATE=RUNNABLE]: Parameter(s): [com.gs.nta.menus.HelpMenuProvider@2ee9de63]
[ENTER] (2021-12-01T14:33:28.240156Z): [SEQ 33]: com.gs.nta.NTApp.buildSubMenus - Building sub-menus... | (Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 [ID=16; PRIORITY=6; STATE=RUNNABLE]: Parameter(s): [com.gs.nta.menus.NewMenuProvider@15d4f1c4]
TRACE (2021-12-01T14:33:28.240356Z): [SEQ 34]: com.gs.nta.NTApp.buildSubMenus - Checking menus.getSize() > 1: false | (Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 [ID=16; PRIORITY=6; STATE=RUNNABLE]: Parameter(s): [com.gs.nta.menus.NewMenuProvider@15d4f1c4]
TRACE (2021-12-01T14:33:28.240641Z): [SEQ 35]: com.gs.nta.NTApp.buildSubMenus - Got menu, javax.swing.JMenu[fileMenu,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalBorders$MenuItemBorder@74ee4a2b,flags=256,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=2,left=2,bottom=2,right=2],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=false,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=false,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=File], from the menubar on the mainFrame. | (Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 [ID=16; PRIORITY=6; STATE=RUNNABLE]: Parameter(s): [com.gs.nta.menus.NewMenuProvider@15d4f1c4]
[ENTER] (2021-12-01T14:33:28.241015Z): [SEQ 36]: com.gs.nta.NTApp.createJMenu - Creating a java.awt.Menu from the MenuProvider: com.gs.nta.menus.NewMenuProvider@15d4f1c4 | (Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 [ID=16; PRIORITY=6; STATE=RUNNABLE]: Parameter(s): [com.gs.nta.menus.NewMenuProvider@15d4f1c4]
[EXIT] (2021-12-01T14:33:28.243433Z): [SEQ 37]: com.gs.nta.NTApp.createJMenu - Menu javax.swing.JMenu[fileNewMenu,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalBorders$MenuItemBorder@74ee4a2b,flags=256,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=2,left=2,bottom=2,right=2],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=false,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=false,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=New] created and returned. | (Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 [ID=16; PRIORITY=6; STATE=RUNNABLE]: Parameter(s): [com.gs.nta.menus.NewMenuProvider@15d4f1c4]
[EXIT] (2021-12-01T14:33:28.248355Z): [SEQ 38]: com.gs.nta.NTApp.buildSubMenus - Added the menu created from MenuProvider (com.gs.nta.menus.NewMenuProvider@15d4f1c4) to the menubar. | (Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 [ID=16; PRIORITY=6; STATE=RUNNABLE]: Parameter(s): [com.gs.nta.menus.NewMenuProvider@15d4f1c4]
TRACE (2021-12-01T14:33:28.248355Z): [SEQ 39]: com.gs.nta.NTApp.buildSubMenus - Added the menu created from MenuProvider (com.gs.nta.menus.NewMenuProvider@15d4f1c4) to the menubar. | (Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 [ID=16; PRIORITY=6; STATE=RUNNABLE]: Parameter(s): [com.gs.nta.menus.NewMenuProvider@15d4f1c4]
TRACE (2021-12-01T14:33:28.248838Z): [SEQ 40]: com.gs.nta.NTApp.buildSubMenus - Got menu, javax.swing.JMenu[editMenu,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalBorders$MenuItemBorder@74ee4a2b,flags=256,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=2,left=2,bottom=2,right=2],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=false,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=false,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=Edit], from the menubar on the mainFrame. | (Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 [ID=16; PRIORITY=6; STATE=RUNNABLE]: Parameter(s): [com.gs.nta.menus.NewMenuProvider@15d4f1c4]
TRACE (2021-12-01T14:33:28.249261Z): [SEQ 41]: com.gs.nta.NTApp.buildSubMenus - (p.getOwnerName()=fileMenu) != (m.getName()=editMenu): moving on... | (Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 [ID=16; PRIORITY=6; STATE=RUNNABLE]: Parameter(s): [com.gs.nta.menus.NewMenuProvider@15d4f1c4]
TRACE (2021-12-01T14:33:28.249519Z): [SEQ 42]: com.gs.nta.NTApp.buildSubMenus - Got menu, javax.swing.JMenu[viewMenu,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalBorders$MenuItemBorder@74ee4a2b,flags=256,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=2,left=2,bottom=2,right=2],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=false,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=false,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=View], from the menubar on the mainFrame. | (Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 [ID=16; PRIORITY=6; STATE=RUNNABLE]: Parameter(s): [com.gs.nta.menus.NewMenuProvider@15d4f1c4]
TRACE (2021-12-01T14:33:28.251184Z): [SEQ 43]: com.gs.nta.NTApp.buildSubMenus - (p.getOwnerName()=fileMenu) != (m.getName()=viewMenu): moving on... | (Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 [ID=16; PRIORITY=6; STATE=RUNNABLE]: Parameter(s): [com.gs.nta.menus.NewMenuProvider@15d4f1c4]
TRACE (2021-12-01T14:33:28.251751Z): [SEQ 44]: com.gs.nta.NTApp.buildSubMenus - Got menu, javax.swing.JMenu[toolsMenu,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalBorders$MenuItemBorder@74ee4a2b,flags=256,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=2,left=2,bottom=2,right=2],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=false,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=false,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=Tools], from the menubar on the mainFrame. | (Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 [ID=16; PRIORITY=6; STATE=RUNNABLE]: Parameter(s): [com.gs.nta.menus.NewMenuProvider@15d4f1c4]
TRACE (2021-12-01T14:33:28.253902Z): [SEQ 45]: com.gs.nta.NTApp.buildSubMenus - (p.getOwnerName()=fileMenu) != (m.getName()=toolsMenu): moving on... | (Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 [ID=16; PRIORITY=6; STATE=RUNNABLE]: Parameter(s): [com.gs.nta.menus.NewMenuProvider@15d4f1c4]
TRACE (2021-12-01T14:33:28.254924Z): [SEQ 46]: com.gs.nta.NTApp.buildSubMenus - Got menu, javax.swing.JMenu[helpMenu,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalBorders$MenuItemBorder@74ee4a2b,flags=256,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=2,left=2,bottom=2,right=2],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=false,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=false,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=Help], from the menubar on the mainFrame. | (Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 [ID=16; PRIORITY=6; STATE=RUNNABLE]: Parameter(s): [com.gs.nta.menus.NewMenuProvider@15d4f1c4]
TRACE (2021-12-01T14:33:28.255386Z): [SEQ 47]: com.gs.nta.NTApp.buildSubMenus - (p.getOwnerName()=fileMenu) != (m.getName()=helpMenu): moving on... | (Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 [ID=16; PRIORITY=6; STATE=RUNNABLE]: Parameter(s): [com.gs.nta.menus.NewMenuProvider@15d4f1c4]
[EXIT] (2021-12-01T14:33:28.255617Z): [SEQ 48]: com.gs.nta.NTApp.buildSubMenus - Sub-menus have all been added to the menu system. | (Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 [ID=16; PRIORITY=6; STATE=RUNNABLE]: Parameter(s): [com.gs.nta.menus.NewMenuProvider@15d4f1c4]
[EXIT] (2021-12-01T14:33:28.255792Z): [SEQ 49]: com.gs.nta.NTApp.buildMainMenu - Menu system built. | (Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 [ID=16; PRIORITY=6; STATE=RUNNABLE]
[ENTER] (2021-12-01T14:33:28.255941Z): [SEQ 50]: com.gs.nta.NTApp.addMenuItems - Adding menu items to the menus... | (Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 [ID=16; PRIORITY=6; STATE=RUNNABLE]
CONFIG (2021-12-01T14:33:28.256095Z): [SEQ 51]: com.gs.nta.NTApp.addMenuItems - Getting all registered menu commands... | (Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 [ID=16; PRIORITY=6; STATE=RUNNABLE]
TRACE (2021-12-01T14:33:28.264841Z): [SEQ 52]: com.gs.nta.NTApp.addMenuItems - Retrieved a total of 3 menu commands. | (Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 [ID=16; PRIORITY=6; STATE=RUNNABLE]
CONFIG (2021-12-01T14:33:28.265224Z): [SEQ 53]: com.gs.nta.NTApp.addMenuItems - Sorted the menu commands. Now loading them into the application menus... | (Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 [ID=16; PRIORITY=6; STATE=RUNNABLE]
[ENTER] (2021-12-01T14:33:28.265478Z): [SEQ 54]: com.gs.nta.NTApp.createJMenuItem - Creating a javax.swing.JMenuItem from the MenuProvider: com.gs.nta.menus.ExitCommand@514e805f | (Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 [ID=16; PRIORITY=6; STATE=RUNNABLE]: Parameter(s): [com.gs.nta.menus.ExitCommand@514e805f]
```

Comment: What is `getContext()` and `getActionMap(someClass)`? Standard swing just has `getActionMap()`. Are you using jdesktop perhaps? The full stacktrace and message of that exception is also missing. You've pasted a lot, but not the most important parts.

Comment: ***UPDATE***: I tried to create a marker interface called `ActionsClass` that would simply mark any class that contains a method decorated with the `@Action` annotation, then updated my `Plugin` interface to have the method `public default Class<ActionsClass> getActionsClass() { return Actions.class; }`, but still get the same `IllegalArgumentException` for a `null ClassLoader`. So, I am still stuck on this...

Comment: @rzwitserloot, my apologies...Yes, I am using jdesktop AppFramework (slightly updated) and I am posting the stacktrace now.

Answer (score 0):

While reviewing the `org.jdesktop.application.ApplicationAction` class, I discovered my (extremely rookie) mistake in the `addMenuItem` method. The line of code that was blowing up with the `IllegalArgumentException` was:

```java
ApplicationActionmap actMap = getContext().getActionMap(c.getClass());
```

I discovered the mistake in that line while reviewing the `ApplicationAction` class' source code to be sure that I did not break something in it when I was updating it. I discovered this - You do not pass a class to `getActionMap`, but an instance of the class:

```java
actMap = getContext().getActionMap(c.getClass()); // WRONG!
actMap = getContext().getActionMap(c)) // Correct!!!
```

Therefore, I was simply passing the wrong parameter in order to get my actions from my `MenuCommand` instance.

[SOLVED] Pass an instance of the class that contains the action to `getActionMap`, not the class itself.